# Using pipe in Windows Command line

Tags: windows, command-line, pipe

I'm trying to pipe a string into another command. The following snippet shows an example which does not work: It only starts Telnet, but does not "type" `open 1.2.3.4` into the running telnet application.

`echo open 1.2.3.4|telnet`

How can I "write" `open 1.2.3.4` after Telnet has been started?

(I know that there is `telnet 1.2.3.4` - this is only a sample...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Telnet in Windows is not scriptable.  This free tool is.

> Telnet Scripting Tool v.1.0
>    by Albert Yale ay@aci.qc.ca